# Is it possible to normalize a symmetric matrix without breaking symmetry?

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, symmetric-matrices, adjacency-matrix

To add a bit more detail to the question in the title, I have an adjacency matrix of a graph, which is symmetric. Symmetric adjacent matrices have nice theoretical properties. However, they break down when I naively normalize the matrix (e.g. so that each row sum to 1), since it's no longer symmetric. Are there ways to get around this issue?

Comment: Well, what exactly do you want to accomplish with your normalization? As you yourself noted, what you proposed does not work -- but maybe there's something else you could try. What we try depends on what you want to accomplish.

Comment: https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00569250v3/document